# Create a BAR graph using PHP and a text file _interesting

Tags: php, graphics, text, graph

I have  a .txt file , the name of which will have a date .

Inside this there are HOURS . for example, 2AM, 0.5 ,1, 0.5 and so on .
 - What this means is the graph starts 2 AM .
 - Use one color1 on bar graph for 0.5 hours.
 - Use ANOTHER color2 on bar graph for the NEXT 1 hour .
 - use color1 again for the NEXT o.5 hours ... and so on .

I looked at a lot of libraries but there is no way I can create a Y axis specifically for a 2 hour granularity (using the chart method ) ...

How do i easily achieve this result , by reading dynamically from the text file ?

Someone please help .

Comment: Have you looked at google charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a similar thing in Java. My PHP wrote out a file, and then called a Java program to do the graphing after parsing the file. I used JFreeChart, but if I was doing it now I'd take a look at jpowered. You can check out some of what I did on my [blog](http://brian-stinar.blogspot.com/2009/08/leader-tech.html). Basically though, my approach was

1.) Find a good charting package.

2.) Write a wrapper for my web software that would interface with that package using files.

3.) Call the package to generate an image.

4.) Delete my temp files.

5.) Link to the newly generated image in the HTML I am serving.

6.) Once every few hours, sweep my image generation directory and delete all the images.

It looks like if you check out jpowered, you might not have to roll your own like I did.

I hope this helps,

-Brian J. Stinar-